# what wordpress theme is this? and is there a way to tell wordpress themes being used for all sites?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to figure out the theme for this site:

moneymachinefactory dot org

I know sometimes you can see it in the page source. in this case, i can't, but i know they're using wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that it's Wordpress, but that would be they went through great lengths to disguise that fact. Especially since this URL fails: http://moneymachinefactory.org/wp-admin , it could be expression engine, drupal or mambo or something else. Good luck, I would just email them and ask.

Comment: The correct URL is http://moneymachinefactory.org/blog/wp-admin,  but still it can be a custom theme or whatever...

Answer (score 0):

The blog http://moneymachinefactory.org/blog/  uses WP, but the other pages are static.

The style sheet in the WP theme doesn't have a standard WP style sheet header with theme info and is loaded from root instead of wp-content/themes/themename/style.css: http://moneymachinefactory.org/gzip.php?f0=style.css

They are probably rewriting the typical WP URLs with .htaccess. It's getting to be a popular thing to do for (some) security and possibly to (somewhat) protect designs.